# Joining 3+ tables using SQL displaying too many results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship, multiple-tables

im trying to create a query to join these tables together using this method below.  However it is repeating results and they are not linking up correctly. as in the same rating comment would be on about 4/5 different results etc. its producing 18ish results when im expecting 3. would anyone be willing to help me with this problem?

```
SELECT a.Company_name, 
       f.Job_ID, 
       f.Job_Name, 
       b.User_Name, 
       c.Comments, 
       c.Reliability, 
       c.Rating
FROM company a, 
     Users b, 
     Ratings c, 
     UserCompJobRating d,
     Company_Job e, 
     Jobs f
WHERE d.Comp_job_ID = e.Comp_Job_ID
     AND b.users_ID = d.users_ID
     AND c.Rating_ID = d.Rating_ID;
```

Many Thanks,

Andrew

ok i tried this and it is saying e.Users_ID is an unknown column in 'on clause'

```
SELECT a.Company_name, 
   b.Job_ID, 
   b.Job_Name, 
   c.User_Name, 
   d.Comments, 
   d.Reliability, 
   d.Rating
FROM Company a, UserCompJobRating e, Jobs b
INNER JOIN Users c
   ON c.Users_ID = e.Users_ID
inner join Company_Job f
    on e.Comp_Job_ID = f.Comp_Job_ID
inner join Ratings d
    on d.Rating_ID = e.Rating_ID;
```

I'm assuming im close, however way off at the same time?

Ill try to give you some more information:

UserCompJobRating has a primary key UCJR_ID and 3 foreign keys of Comp_Job_ID, Users_ID and Rating_ID

Company_Job table as a primary key Comp_Job_ID, and 2 foreign keys Job_ID, Company_ID

Ratings Table has just the Rating_ID as a primary key and the rest just to do with the rating information

Users Table has a Users_ID as a primary key and basic user information address etc etc

Jobs Table has a Job_ID primary key and basic information about the job, such as name, price, etc.

Company Table has Company_ID as a primary key and the basic company information, similar to the Users table.

Here are the definations:

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `Company_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Company_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CAddress` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CTown` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CPostcode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `CTelephone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Company_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `company_job` (
  `Comp_Job_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Company_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Job_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Comp_Job_ID`),
  KEY `Company_ID_idx` (`Company_ID`),
  KEY `Job_ID_idx` (`Job_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Company_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Company_ID`) REFERENCES `company` (`Company_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON         UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Job_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Job_ID`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`Job_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO     ACTION

CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `Job_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Job_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Job_Cost` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_Avg_Time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_Avg_Cost` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_Description` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Company_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Job_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `Rating_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Comments` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reliability` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Rating_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `usercompjobrating` (
  `UCJR_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Comp_Job_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rating_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Users_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UCJR_ID`),
  KEY `Comp_Job_ID_idx` (`Comp_Job_ID`),
  KEY `Rating_ID_idx` (`Rating_ID`),
  KEY `User_ID_idx` (`Users_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Comp_Job_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Comp_Job_ID`) REFERENCES `company_job` (`Comp_Job_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Rating_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Rating_ID`) REFERENCES `ratings` (`Rating_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Users_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Users_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`Users_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Users_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `UAddress` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `UTown` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `UPostcode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `UTelephone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `UDOB` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Users_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: You have six tables and three join conditions.  You have a Cartesian product problem.  You should learn proper `join` syntax so you don't have this problem.

Comment: You wouldnt mind showing me how i could do the join with these tables? its been wrecking my head for a good 3 hrs now lol. i orignally tried the join but it wasnt working, so found a link online which used that method, but that method has seemed to made a balls of it aswell

Comment: . . You need to edit your question to show the definition of the tables.

Comment: I think namphibian just done that for me? lol

Comment: @AndrewGlass nope just formatted the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query needs to look something like this i.e. use this form

```
SELECT a.Company_name, 
   f.Job_ID, 
   f.Job_Name, 
   b.User_Name, 
   c.Comments, 
   c.Reliability, 
   c.Rating
FROM company a
    INNER JOIN Users b
       ON a.???? = b.???
```

Since I dont have your table definitions I cant help you with the JOIN conditions. Show us the tables definition and we would be able to help.

**UPDATE:**

So based on your table structures you will be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM company cmp
INNER JOIN company_job cmpjb
    ON cmp.Company_ID = cmpjb.Company_ID
INNER JOIN jobs jb
    ON cmpjb.Job_ID = jb.Job_ID
INNER JOIN usercompjobrating ucmpjbr
    ON ucmpjbr.Comp_Job_ID = ucmpjbr.Comp_Job_ID
INNER JOIN users usr 
    ON usr.Users_id = ucmpjbr.Users_ID
INNER JOIN ratings rat
   ON rat.Rating_ID = ucmpjbr.Rating_ID
```

Note you cannot use the folder table in this join as there are no primary/foreign key relationships to any of the other tables from the folder table.

I would suggest that you carefully dissect this query and let me know if you need to understand the details.

Comment: I am looking to join the Users.users_id with the UsersCompJobRating.Users_id

The Company_Job.Comp_Job_id with the UsersCompJobRating.Comp_Job_ID

And the Rating.Ratings_ID with the UsersCompJobRating.Ratings_ID

Comment: or do you want a list of all the Columns within all the tables?

Comment: I updated the question if you would mind taking another look?

Comment: @AndrewGlass please run the following commands on the database  for each table and update your question with the outputs `SHOW CREATE TABLE company

Comment: cheers for that lad. there was a small typo but i amended your answer and saved it. thanks for the help

Comment: i remember why i added a Company_ID to the Jobs table. its so the company_job table will auto fill with data of which job is allocated to which company once entered. i was tryin to make the foreign key join there but it wouldnt allow it... would you know why?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to clarify, what is company_id in table jobs?

```
select ... (necessary fields to select)
from company c
join company_job cj using (company_id)
join jobs j using (job_id)
join usercompjobrating ucjr using (comp_job_id)
join ratings using (rating_Id)
join users using (users_id)
```

Comment: i knew that would be mentioned, noticed that myself.  i had put it in by accident and never removed it.

join company_job cj using (comp_job_id) <-- this is throwing up the error 1054 unknown column... same error ive been getting flat out too, why is it unknown when its definately a column? :/

Comment: oops my bad, sorry :D wrong answer...let me revise in a minute